# Unable to stylize Bitmap having different height and width

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-bitmap, tensorflow-lite

I am using one of the Tensorflow models provided by Google in the codelabs to apply Artistic Styles on the images.

I am using the below code to apply styles:

```
  private fun stylizeImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    val intValues = IntArray(desiredWidth * desiredHeight)
    val floatValues = FloatArray(desiredWidth * desiredHeight* 3)

    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)

    for (i in 0 until intValues.size) {
        val value = intValues[i]
        floatValues[i * 3] = ((value shr 16) and 0xFF) / 255.0f
        floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = ((value shr 8) and 0xFF) / 255.0f
        floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (value and 0xFF) / 255.0f
    }
    // Copy the input data into TensorFlow.
    inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, floatValues, 1, bitmap.width.toLong(), bitmap.height.toLong(), 3)
    inferenceInterface.feed(STYLE_NODE, styleVals, NUM_STYLES.toLong())

    // Execute the output node's dependency sub-graph.
    inferenceInterface.run(arrayOf(OUTPUT_NODE), false)

    // Copy the data from TensorFlow back into our array.
    inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, floatValues)

    for (i in 0 until intValues.size) {
        intValues[i] = (0xFF000000.toInt()
                or ((floatValues[i * 3] * 255).toInt() shl 16)
                or ((floatValues[i * 3 + 1] * 255).toInt() shl 8)
                or (floatValues[i * 3 + 2] * 255).toInt())
    }

    val newBm = Bitmap.createBitmap(intValues, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    imageView.setImageBitmap(newBm)
}
```

The problem is that the above code works fine if the dimensions of the `desiredWidth` and the `desiredHeight` are the same (Square images). If the dimensions are different (Rectangular images), the output image is not as expected and some patterns are repeated as shown below.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify -- are you using TensorFlow Lite or TensorFlow? Could you share more information about the model architecture?

Comment: @miaout17 I am using TensorFlow Android (Version 1.3.0) and using the model given at this link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-style-transfer-android/#0

Comment: If you input an image that is square, but larger than example you gave does it resize it? My guess is that it is resizing the inputs to a specific hard coded size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getScaleType() to return the image scaling type?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView